# Why anything is drawn on the screen?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, animation

I´m trying to do a simple 7 segment display and to test it I want to make a simple animation which displays the numbers in order with a separation between number draw of 1 second and this must run indefinitely but I cannot figure out how to draw the display itself (Implementing the animation, without the animation I know how to print the numbers one by one).

PD: I give you all the source code just for you to have it if anyone needs it but the "animation" is located on line 120 where I define the Thread to run the animation.

Source code:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private CustomRectangle custRect = null;
private JButton btnCancel;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public MainWindow() {
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);
    setSize(400, 400);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    custRect = new CustomRectangle(getContentPane().getSize());
    getContentPane().add(custRect);
    getContentPane().add(getBtnCancel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private Color complementaryColor(Color background) {
    int alpha = background.getAlpha();
    int red = background.getRed();
    int blue = background.getBlue();
    int green = background.getGreen();

    // find compliments
    red = (~red) & 0xff;
    blue = (~blue) & 0xff;
    green = (~green) & 0xff;

    return new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
}

private JButton getBtnCancel() {
    if (btnCancel == null) {
        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnCancel.setBackground(null);
        btnCancel.setBorder(null);
        btnCancel.setForeground(complementaryColor(getContentPane().getBackground()));
        btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
    }
    return btnCancel;
}

private class CustomRectangle extends JComponent {

    private byte[] nums = new byte[] { 0x7E, 0x30, 0x6D, 0x79, 0x33, 0x5B, 0x5F, 0x70, 0x7F, 0x7B };

    private double mainWidth = 0.0;
    private double mainHeight = 0.0;
    private Graphics2D g2d = null;

    public CustomRectangle(Dimension size) {
        mainWidth = size.getWidth();
        mainHeight = size.getHeight();
    }

    public byte[] getNums() {
        return nums;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Thread th = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
                            generalCall(nums[i]);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };th.start();
    }

    public void generalCall(byte val) {
        drawAHoursHigh(val);
        drawBHoursHigh(val);
        drawCHoursHigh(val);
        drawDHoursHigh(val);
        drawEHoursHigh(val);
        drawFHoursHigh(val);
        drawGHoursHigh(val);

    }
    private Color getColor(byte val, int shift) {
        int r = 255;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int a = 255 * (val >> shift) & 1;

        System.out.println("R: " + r + " G: " + g + " B: " + b + " Alpha: " + a);

        if (a == 0)
            return new Color(15, 15, 15);
        else
            return new Color(r, g, b);
    }

    private void drawAHoursHigh(byte val) {
        System.out.print("A: ");
        Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 20, 78, 18, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 6));
        g2d.fill(a);
        g2d.draw(a);
    }

    private void drawBHoursHigh(byte val) {
        System.out.print("B: ");
        Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(140, 40, 18, 98, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 5));
        g2d.fill(b);
        g2d.draw(b);
    }

    private void drawCHoursHigh(byte val) {
        System.out.print("C: ");
        Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(140, 160, 18, 98, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 4));
        g2d.fill(c);
        g2d.draw(c);
    }

    private void drawDHoursHigh(byte val) {
        System.out.print("D: ");
        Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 260, 78, 18, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 3));
        g2d.fill(d);
        g2d.draw(d);
    }

    private void drawEHoursHigh(byte val) {
        System.out.print("E: ");
        Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(40, 160, 18, 98, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 2));
        g2d.fill(e);
        g2d.draw(e);
    }

    private void drawFHoursHigh(byte val) {
        System.out.print("F: ");
        Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(40, 40, 18, 98, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 1));
        g2d.fill(f);
        g2d.draw(f);
    }

    private void drawGHoursHigh(byte val) {
        System.out.print("G: ");
        Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 140, 78, 18, 10, 10);
        g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 0));
        g2d.fill(g);
        g2d.draw(g);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't use `private Graphics2D g2d = null;` - You should never be maintaining a reference to any `Graphics` context you didn't create yourself

Comment: Why are you creating a thread in the `paintComponent`?  You'll end up with an infinite number of running threads!

Comment: *I want to make a simple animation"* - Then start with a Swing `Timer`

Answer (score 0):

First, go read:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

for more information on how painting works in Swing.

Next, go read:

- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

to get a better understanding of the concurrency issue in Swing - the short version, Swing is NOT thread safe and is single threaded.  This raises a number of issues when you want to perform repeated actions that update the UI.

Then, go read [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a feasible solution.

Let's start identifying the core problems...

This...

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

is generally a bad idea, but you're not using it anyway, so it's just white noise

This...

```
custRect = new CustomRectangle(getContentPane().getSize());
```

is erroneous, because at the time you request the size of he `contentPane`, it's not been realised or layout on the screen, so it's result is `0x0`.  You shouldn't be relying on this anyway and if you want to know the size of the container, request it when you actually need it.

Next...

```
private Graphics2D g2d = null;
```

You should never maintain a reference to any graphics context you didn't create.  In Swing, the context is shared amongst all the components been painted, meaning that it could be dirty, with other content, or clipped to exclude the area you want painted.

And finally....

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    Thread th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
                        generalCall(nums[i]);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };th.start();
}
```

`paintComponent` will be called when ever Swing thinks your component needs to be repainted, when first realised, this could be a number of times in quick succession, meaning you now have a number of `Thread`s running.

Paint should do one job, paint the current context of the component, nothing else.  In your case, a Swing `Timer` would be a more viable and safer solution.

And, cleaned up, it might look something like...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private CustomRectangle custRect = null;
    private JButton btnCancel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        custRect = new CustomRectangle();
        getContentPane().add(custRect);
        getContentPane().add(getBtnCancel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private Color complementaryColor(Color background) {
        int alpha = background.getAlpha();
        int red = background.getRed();
        int blue = background.getBlue();
        int green = background.getGreen();

        // find compliments
        red = (~red) & 0xff;
        blue = (~blue) & 0xff;
        green = (~green) & 0xff;

        return new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
    }

    private JButton getBtnCancel() {
        if (btnCancel == null) {
            btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            btnCancel.setBackground(null);
            btnCancel.setBorder(null);
            btnCancel.setForeground(complementaryColor(getContentPane().getBackground()));
            btnCancel.setFocusPainted(false);
        }
        return btnCancel;
    }

    private class CustomRectangle extends JComponent {

        private byte[] nums = new byte[]{0x7E, 0x30, 0x6D, 0x79, 0x33, 0x5B, 0x5F, 0x70, 0x7F, 0x7B};

        public CustomRectangle() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public byte[] getNums() {
            return nums;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                generalCall(g2d, nums[i]);
            }
        }

        public void generalCall(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            drawAHoursHigh(g2d, val);
            drawBHoursHigh(g2d, val);
            drawCHoursHigh(g2d, val);
            drawDHoursHigh(g2d, val);
            drawEHoursHigh(g2d, val);
            drawFHoursHigh(g2d, val);
            drawGHoursHigh(g2d, val);
        }

        private Color getColor(byte val, int shift) {
            int r = 255;
            int g = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int a = 255 * (val >> shift) & 1;

            System.out.println("R: " + r + " G: " + g + " B: " + b + " Alpha: " + a);

            if (a == 0) {
                return new Color(15, 15, 15);
            } else {
                return new Color(r, g, b);
            }
        }

        private void drawAHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            System.out.print("A: ");
            Shape a = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 20, 78, 18, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 6));
            g2d.fill(a);
            g2d.draw(a);
        }

        private void drawBHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            System.out.print("B: ");
            Shape b = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(140, 40, 18, 98, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 5));
            g2d.fill(b);
            g2d.draw(b);
        }

        private void drawCHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            System.out.print("C: ");
            Shape c = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(140, 160, 18, 98, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 4));
            g2d.fill(c);
            g2d.draw(c);
        }

        private void drawDHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            System.out.print("D: ");
            Shape d = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 260, 78, 18, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 3));
            g2d.fill(d);
            g2d.draw(d);
        }

        private void drawEHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            System.out.print("E: ");
            Shape e = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(40, 160, 18, 98, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 2));
            g2d.fill(e);
            g2d.draw(e);
        }

        private void drawFHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            System.out.print("F: ");
            Shape f = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(40, 40, 18, 98, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 1));
            g2d.fill(f);
            g2d.draw(f);
        }

        private void drawGHoursHigh(Graphics2D g2d, byte val) {
            System.out.print("G: ");
            Shape g = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(60, 140, 78, 18, 10, 10);
            g2d.setColor(getColor(val, 0));
            g2d.fill(g);
            g2d.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```